# Why am I getting a weird answer when I try to check the value of a field?

Tags: c++, object, parameters, field

I have this little problem in C++:

I made an object called `Angle` in a file called angle.cpp. 
It has a field called `degrees` of type `double`.

Here is my constructor for it:

```
Angle::Angle(double deg)
{
   degrees = deg;
}
```

I have the proper declarations for my Angle class in a separate header file as standard.
Everything looks simple and right so far.

However in my main.cpp I have this in one of my functions:

```
double value;
cin >> value;
Angle angle = Angle(value);
```

At this point the `angle` object's `degrees` should have whatever value I typed into `cin` right?

I have another function called `getDegrees()` in angle.cpp that just returns whatever `degrees` is, since I made `degrees` private in the header file

but when I check with a `cout << angle.getDegrees()`, I get a weird number like `6.64651e-315`, which is definitely not what I gave `value` through `cin`.

Comment: What do the `Angle.h` look like, and what does the rest of your `Angle.cpp` look like?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you are posting. You would get the strange result if your "cin" input cannot be parsed correctly as a double (say, a text string instead of a number). Either that or you are doing some mistake in the code you are not showing.

Comment: Did you try to `std::cout` the value of `value` before you send it to constructor to verify that it was inputted correctly?

Comment: Make sure `cin` parsed it correctly, as has been stated. Also, are you using different instances of your `Angle` object?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

**1) Initialize "value"** when you declare it as shown below so that it doesn't contain random code.

**2) Flush the cin buffer**:

```
double value = 0;

// Clear the cin error flag
cin.clear();

// Ignore to the end of line
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')

cin >> value; 
Angle angle = Angle(value);
```

I hope that helps.

Note that you should call both cin.clear (clears error flag) and cin.ignore (clears out the buffer) AFTER using cin as shown below.  You may have read in some data earlier in the program and not flushed the buffer.  Not flushing the buffer after reading in data can sometimes leave data in the cin buffer that shows up the next time you read data.

For example, if you attempt to read in data with cin and it generates an error, this sets the error flag causing all future cin actions to fail (cin.clear resets the flag).  Furthermore, the data that caused the error may still be sitting in the cin buffer (cin.ignore flushes it out).

```
cin >> value;  
cin.clear();  // Always call these two commands after using cin
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

One final comment:
You will often see this shorter format for cin.ignore

```
cin.ignore(10000, '\n')
```

That also skips to the next newline by ignoring up to 10000 characters but the first way shown above is the proper C++ standards compliant technique.

If you post your entire main.cpp and angle.cpp, I'm sure 10 people will jump on the correct answer in under 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check (or post here) the definition of `getDegrees`   (here is sample code of one can expect)

```
double Angle::getDegrees()
{
    return degrees;
}
```

Note:
not related to your problem, but your constructor can be also wrote as:

```
Angle::Angle(double deg) : degrees(deg) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my Mac:

```
#include <iostream>

class Angle
{
  double degrees;

  public:
  Angle(double deg) { degrees = deg;}
  Angle() {};
  double getDegrees() { return degrees;}
 };

int main (int argc, char** argv)

{
  double d;
  std::cout << "Give me some degrees: ";
  std::cin >> d;
  Angle a = Angle(d);
  std::cout << a.getDegrees() << "\n";
  std::cout << Angle(d).getDegrees() << "\n";
  Angle b;
  std::cout << b.getDegrees() << "\n";
}
```

And I got:

```
Give me some degrees: 24
24
24
6.95323e-310
```

And so I suspect that you are getDegrees'ing from an uninitialized Angle.  Did you define the copy constructor like this, maybe:

```
Angle(Angle& angle){};
```